# Css Custom Loader Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

### My Custom CSS Loader

```css
.LoaderWrap {
 width:100%;
 margin-top:25px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

.sampleContainer {
 float:left;
 height: 40px;
 width: 100%;
 margin:10px 10px 20px 10px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
.loader,
.loader.Large {
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
.dot,
.loader.Large .dot {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top:20px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
  background: #888;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}
.loader.Large .dot {
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 -webkit-border-radius:12px;
 -moz-border-radius:12px;
   border-radius: 12px;
}

/** Large Dots **/
.loader.Large .dot_1 {
 animation: LargeDot1 1.5s linear infinite;
 left:38px;
}
@keyframes LargeDot1 {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-38px); }
  25% { transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-38px); }
  75% { transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-38px); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(-38px); }
}

.loader.Large .dot_2 {
 left:76px;
 animation: LargeDot2 1.5s linear infinite;
   animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
@keyframes LargeDot2 {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-38px); }
  25% { transform: rotate(-180deg) translateX(-38px); }
  75% { transform: rotate(-180deg) translateX(-38px); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg) translateX(-38px); }
}

.loader.Large .dot_3 {
 left:38px;
 animation: LargeDot3 1.5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes LargeDot3 {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(38px); }
  25% { transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(38px); }
  75% { transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(38px); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(38px); }
}

.loader.Large .dot_4 {
 left:76px;
 animation: LargeDot4 1.5s linear infinite;
   animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
@keyframes LargeDot4 {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(38px); }
  25% { transform: rotate(-180deg) translateX(38px); }
  75% { transform: rotate(-180deg) translateX(38px); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg) translateX(38px); }
}
```

```html
<div class="LoaderWrap clearfix">
  <div class="loader Large">
    <span class="dot dot_1"></span>
    <span class="dot dot_2"></span>
    <span class="dot dot_3"></span>
    <span class="dot dot_4"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

### So What's Wrong?

Nothing is 'wrong' as such, feel free to use this loader by all means! However I would like to make this more interesting, turn the dots into stars for example and maybe even go one step further by having the dots (circles) transform into different shapes.

As much as I love CSS and consider myself to be an expert, animating CSS is fairly new to me whereas this is the first CSS animation I have made and I want to make this more unique and crazy for the theme of the website I am working on, not to say that I don't love this loader and asking for, call it improving my skills?, means people will also use, but nevertheless, it is a learning path!

### Minimal Question:

How can I have myh dots (circles) as starts **OR** have my dots (circles) tranform into different shapes, whether it is transforming from basic squares to circles or whatnot using pure CSS and/or JS/jQuery?

Comment: look here: http://www.cssportal.com/css3-shapes/

Comment: You could do something like [**this**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNdZpv). With [**GreenSock**](https://greensock.com/morphSVG) it's quite easy to morph between shapes if you use SVG.

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz That is an absolutely interesting and useful link! I've never really gone into SVG's too much but now I think I love them :)